# Remove blank options from select field?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a fairly simple select field with options fetched from a database (Magento) and echoed via

```
foreach ($groups as $a){

    if($a['label'] != NULL){    

        echo "<option value='".$a['value']."'>" . $a['label'] . "<option>";

    }

}
```

My problem is that even with server-side code preventing null fields, I still get empty option fields

I also have this JavaScript to sort my options alphabetically, could this cause me to have blank options?

```
                            function sortlist()
                            {
                                var cl = document.getElementById('group_id');
                                var clTexts = new Array();

                                for(i = 2; i < cl.length; i++)
                                {
                                    clTexts[i-2] =
                                        cl.options[i].text.toUpperCase() + "," +
                                        cl.options[i].text + "," +
                                        cl.options[i].value;
                                }

                                clTexts.sort();

                                for(i = 2; i < cl.length; i++)
                                {
                                    var parts = clTexts[i-2].split(',');

                                    cl.options[i].text = parts[1];
                                    cl.options[i].value = parts[2];
                                }
                            }


                            sortlist();
```

How could one ensure with JavaScript that no *blank* options in a drop-down select are displayed?

Particulars:

Data source for my foreach contains no blank fields

I get as many blank options as legitimate options

The end result source code looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You tried `if(!empty($a['label'])) ` ?

Comment: Better to use if($a['label'] != NULL && $a['label'] != '') rather than relay on JS

Comment: Maybe. if($a['label'] != '')

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira just tried that, same result

Comment: Can you paste the <option/> empty element here?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira I have added to my question to include the faulty source code, this is what is displayed by the browser

Comment: from where your $groups comes??

Comment: From a Magento database, as an array, with no empty fields

Comment: Hey guys why second option field does't contains value attribute ?

Comment: Can you post select's source code? (not from developer console, but the text that is actually returned by browser and can be viewed by pressing ctrl + U)

Comment: @user1680977 No need to post, but upon inspection there are no blank option fields, it looks legitimate, but not for the end-user, very strange issue

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that in the source code of the website (as displayed by ctrl + U) you can see it correcly? In this case, I think I'll need to see at least one sample of the option from the source code to help further.

Comment: @user1680977 Source Code of page = Fine, Inspect Element = shows blank options, PHP code = doesn't allow blank fields. JavaScript = Alphabetises options, End result = 30 blank options and 30 good options

Comment: Then the `$a['value']` or `$a['label']` must contain strange characters such as `<`, `'` or something similar. It might look ok in the source code, bu in the dev console, the browser tries to solve this problem in its own way, creating the empty fields

Comment: Please post the `<php var_dump($groups); ?>`

Comment: The issue is not server-side

Comment: We need to see what you are actually trying to output from the server to troubleshoot effectively.

Comment: I am outputting the correct options. The problem is that blank options (that aren't in the database) are mysteriously appearing in the select box. Possibly due to my JavaScript

Comment: See my updated answer and try changing your PHP foreach loop echo code.

Comment: No idea if this will solve the problem, but your closing tags for `<option>` are missing a slash in the php code.

Comment: @DecentDabbler I feel very stupid. Issue resolved, thankyou, put that in an answer and I will accept

Comment: @zak I just saw [Eko3alpha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29849480/165154) mention it as well already, so give Eko3alpha's answer the check mark. ;-)

Comment: +1 for nobility, it's amazing how 70+ developers have looked at this question and only a few pointed out an unclosed html tag, I suppose we all make mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work just fine, also you don't have a closing  tag which was causing some issues when I was testing.  You should also not echo out every time in the loop.  create a variable and echo once outside the loop.

```
$options = '';
foreach ($groups as $a)
{
    if(!empty($a['label']))
    {
        $options .= "<option value='".$a['value']."'>" . $a['label'] . "</option>";
    }
}
echo $options;
```

Comment: `!= ''` and `!= NULL` are the same thing.  http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php Also you should never use `!= ''` or  `!= NULL` on a multi-dimensional array index when it is equivalent to using `empty()` with the exception that empty also validates `isset()` to prevent an unknown index error. EG: `!empty($a['label'])` is the same as `isset($a['label']) && $a['label'] != ''`

Comment: Yikes, thanks for the catch! You are correct, sorry, I pasted the wrong version of my code.  I created a small test to make sure this would work!

Comment: I completely overlooked this answer, but it solved the issue, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(!empty(trim($a['label']))) {
    ...
```

Once you'll be looking into this solution, you might also come across [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) which is not quite what you need, since your if statement with `isset` would evaluate to true even if it's an empty string.

Comment: Have you checked what exactly is content of `$a['label']` when it looks empty and at the same time it is not null?

Answer (score 0):

Using `empty()` will skip `0` also

```
if(!(!isset($a['label']) || $a['label']=='' || !isset($a['value']) || $a['value']=='')) {
          //logic here
}
```

Comment: Same result as before. I believe this problem to be caused server side

Comment: @zak Can you please some of data from `$groups`

Answer (score 0):

I think NULL is coming as a string. try this

```
foreach ($groups as $a){

if($a['label'] != 'NULL'){ //wrap NULL to single quote   

    echo "<option value='".$a['value']."'>" . $a['label'] . "<option>";

}

}
```

Comment: Surely that will only work when a returned row is actually the string "NULL"?

Answer (score 0):

If `$a['label']` contains 1 more more spaces it won't equal NULL or be empty.

```
foreach ($groups as $a) {
    $label = trim($a['label']);
    $value = trim($a['value']);
    if (!empty($label)) {    
        echo "<option value='$value'>$label<option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no $a['label']'s that are NULL, the problem is client side

Answer (score 0):

Probably your array `$groups` comes with empty values, so try [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$groups = array_filter($groups);
foreach ($groups as $a) {
...
```

Comment: `array_filter` won't work recursively on the multi-dimensional array, need to add a custom function to check the child arrays. See:  http://ideone.com/Mkr1kt

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue I see with your code is you are mixing double and single quotes in your HTML and missing the closing option tag.
`<select id="">` vs `<option value=''>`

You should change your PHP output like so:

```
foreach ($groups as $a) {
    echo '<option value="'.$a['value'].'">' . $a['label'] . '</option>';
}
```

I like using `array_filter` for things like these. It allows you to specify your own method outside of additional condition checks from within your view.

```
$groups = array(
    array(
        'label' => '',
        'value' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'label' => 'test',
        'value' => 'test'
    )
);

function validate($var)
{
    return !empty($var['label']);
}

$groups = array_filter($groups, 'validate');
foreach ($groups as $a) {
    echo "<option value='".$a['value']."'>" . $a['label'] . "<option>";
}
```

http://ideone.com/h0Wk1T

Also unless you are dynamically sorting the values alphabetically with Javascript (onclick/user action) I suggest you sort your groups with PHP after using `array_filter`. A lot less frustration and doesn't rely on client-side compatibility.

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    return strcmp($a['label'], $b['label']);
}

usort($groups, 'cmp');
```

http://ideone.com/OH5vXL

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

> ```
> foreach ($groups as $a){
>
>     if(trim($a['label']) != ''){    
>
>         echo "<option value='".$a['value']."'>" . $a['label'] . "<option>";
>
>     }
>
> }
> ```